# How to use a loop in order to create link inside a navigation list?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop, innerhtml

Using javascript, I have inserted an href inside a navigation bar and would like a loop to repeat the operation for the two remaining items. I want my loop to be inside the function. Why do I end up with three identical links? I need the navigation bar to display HTML, DOM and Javascript. Not HTML, HTML, HTML.

```
        <nav>
            <ul>
                <li class="navigation">HTML</li>
                <li class="navigation">DOM</li>
                <li class="navigation">Javascript</li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
```

```
function newLink () {

    var navigation = document.getElementsByClassName("navigation");
    var existingText = navigation[0].innerHTML;

    document.getElementsByClassName("navigation")[0].innerHTML=  '<a href="'+existingText+'">'+existingText+'</a>';

    for (var i = 0; i < navigation.length; i++)
    {
    navigation[i].innerHTML=  '<a href="'+existingText+'">'+existingText+'</a>';
    }

}
    newLink();
```

Comment: "*a loop to repeat the operation for the two remaining items*" - why wouldn't you use the loop for all three items right away? "*Why do I end up with three identical links?*" - because they all use the same `existingText`.

Comment: What should the loop look like in order to loop the three items right away?

Comment: Exactly as it is, you already loop over all 3 elements with that code :-) I just was wondering why you'd want to special-case the first item.

Comment: Right now, the loop produces HTML, HTML, HTML. I want it to render HTML, DOM, Javascript.

Comment: Yes, then don't do `var existingText = navigation[0].innerHTML;` outside of the loop but `var existingText = navigation[i].innerHTML;` inside the loop!